# Azure service bus: with RootManageSharedAccessKey, still complains 'Listen' claim(s) required?

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-node-sdk

I have an error-handler passed to a service bus client "receive" function and it is firing after setup as follows:

```
  const ns = Namespace.createFromConnectionString(connectionString);
  const client = ns.createQueueClient(queueName);
  const receiver = client.getReceiver();
  receiver.receive(onMessageHandler, onErrorHandler, { autoComplete: false });
```

with the error:
**UnauthorizedError: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation.**

The connection string being used uses the default root shared access key which has all claims (listen, send AND manage). Why am I getting this error / how to fix it? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps anyone but in my case, I had the old `azure-sb` package still kicking around, and it may have been polluting my `node_modules` in some in explicable way. Getting rid of it seems to have gotten rid of the claims complaints.